# Verify if time is between midnight and 1am in PHP

Tags: php, time

I've coded the following line for verifying if time is between midnight (00:00) and 1am clock (01:00). Is it correct?

```
$current_time = strtotime('now');
if ($current_time > strtotime('12:00pm') && $current_time < strtotime('1:00am')) { DO SOMETHING }
```

I'm not sure of that 12:00pm... Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you test the if statement with a series of hard-coded times in $current_time and see how the code reacts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to verify between midday (12:00pm) and 1 am.. 12:00am is midnight. So you should change it to

```
if ($current_time > strtotime('12:00am') && $current_time < strtotime('01:00am')) { DO SOMETHING }
```

Comment: @cale_b Aight, updated it. But there's not much to say, he just confused the 12-hour clock.

Comment: Much better.  This will be far more useful to future visitors.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to know, just if midnight is am or pm! Yeah so dumb I know...

Answer (score 2):

Consider this:

```
<?php

$current_time   =   date('d M Y H:i:s');
$current_hour   =   date('H', strtotime($current_time));

if($current_hour < 1){

    //do something
}

else{

    //do something else
    }

?>
```

'H' will return time in hours only format. As long as the time is between 12:00 am and 1:00 am the condition will return TRUE.